# Call function on [hidden] change

Tags: angular

I have a component which i am showing/hiding using `[hidden]`. Within the component i want some code to run when the component is shown (when hidden is false).

I've tried grabbing the input using `@Input() hidden: boolean` but this overrides the default behaviour.

Is there a way of keeping the default functionality and still listen to the input?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using hidden and not ngIf? because hidden just hides from dom but initailizes it. If you use ngIf you can add that code to ngOnInit

Comment: rename the hidden input inside the component.

Comment: @user8351493 hidden is more smooth, i can switch views (components) instantly. Also this is for a map view (using leaflet) i want the user to be able to keep where they are on the map when switching views.

Comment: How is the hidden tag being toggled? Is it by a user interaction or just if it is specified in the code?

Comment: @CaeSea When the user switches tabs. Similar to this: https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular-JumpStart/blob/master/src/app/customers/customers.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the standard `hidden` property of the component host element in the custom `hidden` input property with a setter:

```
@Input() set hidden(value: boolean) {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.hidden = value;
  console.log("Component is hidden", value);
};

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hc45vc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-div.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting your "hidden" on the root element of your child component or by recoding the "hidden" property like this :

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello!</h1>`
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() set hidden(value: boolean) {
    this._element.nativeElement.hidden = value;
  }

  constructor(private _element: ElementRef) {
  }
}
```